# Is "Forward Voltage @ 1A" equivalent to "Internal Voltage Drop"

Tags: voltage, resistance

I have a problem for an Electrical Engineering 1 subject with information given as "LED Light Internal Series Resistance" = 15.1Ω and "LED Light Internal Voltage Drop" = 9.5V. 
When attempting to model this circuit in Falstad or other circuit simulators I'm not sure how to correctly configure this information. 
The only input option for LEDs in Falstad (Circuit Simulator) are "Forward Voltage @ 1A". I have put a resistor in series with an LED with a resistance value of 15.1 Ohm and set "Forward Voltage Drop @ 1A" of the LED to 9.5V but I'm not sure this is correct. Can somebody explain how these two terms are related?

Comment: Well, this sounds unclear to me as well.

Comment: Glad I'm not alone

Comment: It sounds like a 15.1Ω resistor in series with a chain of five 1.9V LEDs. With a 12V supply you'd get about 166mA through the chain.

Answer (score 1):

Tjhere is not enough information here to make a unique decision.
If the course is designed to help you learn to 'think on your feet' - plough on :-).
If there is meant to be one correct answer, ask for / demand more data.

Similar to what Majenko says, this sounds like a 12V supply targeted LED string BUT without specific or additional advice this is only a conjecture.

I'd have "guessed" 3 LEDs with 9.5V / 3 = 3.166V/LED ~= 3.2V /LED.
~= 3.2V is typical for white LEDs.
Majenko's 5 x 1.9V might be red LEDs.
In either case the voltage drop is an approximation, as LED Vf will vary with current, and current varies with applied voltage, and voltage ... .

As per Majenko's result, Iled expected nominal
I = V/R = (12-9.5) / 15.1 ~= 166 mA.

If this string was used in an automotive application where Vsupply can be eg 14V then if Vled did not vary (but, it would) then Istring 
= V/R = (14-9.5)/15.1 = 530 mA or 3+ times as high as at 12V supply!

In practice VLED will rise as ILED rises, serving to somewhat reduce current rise.
eg if VLED = 3.5V/LED at higher current then at 14V
Istring = (14 - 3 x 3.5) / 15.1 ~= 230 mA.
While less than the above 530 mA, this is still ~= 50% higher than at 12V supply.

A good illustration of why LEDs should be current driven where possible.
A higher series R (and Ferber LEDs to compensate) will have less current variation with voltage, as the higher series resistance more closely approximates a current source.

Comment: I found the answer but am unable to answer my own question. As confusing as it sounds, the intention was to model the LEDs as a voltage source with series resistance. So in this case series resistance of 15.1ohms and a voltage source with current entering the positive terminal (i.e. current source feeding the battery) with a value of 9.5v.